# CakePHP Form->postLink does not work for the first row

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I have a table with all *comissões* saved in the database. In this table, the user can delete any row:

[image]

The delete action is a postLink on the view:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->postLink(
    __('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>'), 
    array(
        'action' => 'delete', $contratos[0]['Contrato']['id'], 
        $comissao['ContratoComissionario']['id']
    ), 
    array(
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 
        'escape' => false, 
        'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 
        'title' => 'delete'
    ), 
    __('Você tem certeza de que deseja deletar essa comissão?')
);
```

?>

This is the controller:

```
public function delete($idContrato = null, $id = null) {
    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    $this->ContratoComissionario->id = $id;
    if (!$this->ContratoComissionario->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Comissão inválida'));
    }
    if ($this->ContratoComissionario->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comissão deletada com sucesso'), 'flash/success');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add', $idContrato));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comissão não pôde ser deletada'), 'flash/error');
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', $idContrato));
}
```

The delete action work like a charm for all rows in the table, but the first. When I click on the first delete icon, the confirm message is showed and nothing else happens.

I figured out the form for the first row is not created. This is the HTML generated for the second icon:

```
<td>
    <form action="/ModuloContratos/ContratoComissionarios/delete/3/11" name="post_55fc1552e0890053880032" id="post_55fc1552e0890053880032" style="display:none;" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    </form>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="if (confirm(&quot;Voc\u00ea tem certeza de que deseja deletar essa comiss\u00e3o?&quot;)) { document.post_55fc1552e0890053880032.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;" data-original-title="delete">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    </a>                                        
</td>
```

And this is the HTML generated for the first icon:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" onclick="if (confirm(&quot;Voc\u00ea tem certeza de que deseja deletar essa comiss\u00e3o?&quot;)) { document.post_55fc1552e0113745519359.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;" data-original-title="delete">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

How could I force postLink to create the form for all the rows? I'm using the CakePHP 2.7.2.